# Why can I not tune up newly bought classical guitar to proper pitches?

Tags: tuning, instruments, classical-guitar

I bought classical guitar yesterday online, and it is impossible to tune the 1st string to E.
I can only tune up to Eb, and if I apply more tension to the string, it looks like it's about to snap.

Is this normal for new nylon strings?

Comment: Did the strings come on the guitar, or did you string it youself?

Comment: Are you absolutely certain it's the right octave E you're tuning to?

Comment: What reference are you using to tune to?

Comment: How do you know *"it looks like it's about to snap"*? Strings tend to be fairly secretive about that information in advance of actually snapping.

Comment: Note: If you bought online, you might need to take it in person to a luthier to make sure everything is set up properly and in good working order. If you ordered from a place that does that maybe you're ok, but if you bought used from another owner or bought a new instrument from a generic retailer like Amazon, then it's needed.

Comment: Are you sure it's an E string? not a B string? Try a new set. You'll be changing them some time anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is normal for new nylon strings on both guitars and [ukuleles](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/24630/is-it-normal-for-new-bought-ukeleles-to-be-out-of-tune-every-few-minutes). The only way around it is tuning to pitch even it feels wrong when you keep turning the tuner and pitch barely changes, and then doing it over again until the strings finally settle.

For your peace of mind it could be a good idea to get a set of spare strings now. You are going to replace the strings anyway at some point.